# How to take file inputs from user on ink?

Tags: ink

I want to take a csv input from the caller so that the csv contents can be loaded to the contract storage as a Vector.

Crates like csv seem to do just that in standard Rust, e.g. using `std::io` or `std::fs::File`. But ink doesn't seem to support the std library.

Why is it not supported? And how can I parse a csv file?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things to unpack here:

- A smart contract environment is highly sandboxed. A smart contract is executed by every node in a blockchain network. This is needed so that the nodes can come to consensus on the state the blockchain will have after the contract has been executed. Therefore every node needs to have the exact same state before the contract is executed, otherwise the results of its execution could differ after executing it. This would be very bad since it's essential for nodes to agree on a common state. Just think of balances ‒ the majority of the network must have a consensus on the account balances, there has to be some common ground truth, otherwise things like the double-spending problem are possible. That's why it can never be possible to access `std::io` or `std::fs::File` in a smart contract ‒ a smart contract could yield entirely different result based on what files a node would have on its local file system.
- For smart contracts it's important that they are small in terms of size, this reduces the gas fees for users as well as the throughput a blockchain can achieve when multiple contracts are called in one block. Operations like parsing a CSV are expensive in terms of computation and it's an anti-pattern to require users to pay for them. *Generally anything that is not strictly required for the state transitions of a smart contract should not be in it.* What you should do instead is have e.g. the user interface already do this parsing and call our contract with the result of it.

In terms of Rust's standard library there is more to say there, but the short answer is that ink! has the [`ink_prelude`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_prelude/) crate, which exposes a number of the primitives that you are likely searching for, so e.g.  `ink_prelude::vec::Vec`. More data structures (like `Mapping`) are available in [`ink_storage`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_storage/), they have been optimized for usage in smart contracts.

If you want more details on this whole topic I recommend reading our FAQ answer to "[Why is Rust's standard library (stdlib) not available in `ink!`?](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/faq/#why-is-rusts-standard-library-stdlib-not-available-in-ink)".

Answer (score 1):

The smart contract is run inside the blockchain in a web assembly sandbox. It has no direct access to any files. A file is however nothing more than a vec of bytes and you could accept that vec as an input to one's contract.

But unless you really need to I would recommend just storing the hash of that file on chain as that will be a lot cheaper and more predictable in terms of gas fees.

The [parachainSystem/enact_authorized_upgrade](https://paritytech.github.io/cumulus/cumulus_pallet_parachain_system/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.enact_authorized_upgrade) is an example of uploading a file.

The [parachainSystem/authorize_upgrade](https://paritytech.github.io/cumulus/cumulus_pallet_parachain_system/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.authorize_upgrade) is an example of uploading a hash of a file.

(EDITOR: Those are examples of it done in pallets. Does anyone have any examples of ink! contracts doing the same?)

Comment: If you just use a `Vec<u8>` as an argument to a contract message the UI should offer you a file upload.